# Marketing Cloud Custom Preference Center - Do I need Publication Lists?

Tags: marketing-cloud, preference-center

Designing a custom preference center and planning to use a data extension instead of OOTB preference Management to store subscriber preferences.

Here is my design

**MasterSubscribersDE** - To store all subscribers

**CustomPreferencesDE** - To store preferences like NewsLetter, ProductInfo etc.

The preference center updates CustomPreferencesDE when a customer updates any preferences and I would use this DE while  creating a segment for a a campaign.

So far good however one thing I can't wrap my head around is Do I still need to manage publication lists for each communication/preference or just use a dummy publication list while sending emails? Because my segment only has subscribers opted-in for a given communication? Also my plan is to log UnsubEvent only for org level Unsubscribes not preference changes(in other words list unsubscribes) because I will update those changes in the DE.

Any issue with just using a dummy publication list for all emails OR you would still recommend a publication list for each preference?

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine not using publication lists. None of the solutions I have built over the last 8 years utilised these, but were built purely based on data extensions. Also, to you point on unsubevents: indeed, I also only use these for a master opt-out, managed on All Subscribers List.

I have written an article about managing preferences on SFMC utilising SSJS and data extension, but you should be fine doing something similar with ampscript. Also, it will give you some more inspiration to what additional features and data extensions which can become useful. You can find it here: https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/consent-management/consent-management-with-salesforce-marketing-cloud/

Comment: Thank you Lukas and appreciate your insight. So just to confirm It is OK choosing a dummy publication list  OR AllSubscribers since email send requires choosing a publication list?

Comment: @sdondeti correct. And here I am always picking All Subs.